# Multiple left joins with afilter on max value of a linked table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my structure.

```
- LIC_LICENCE
    - LIC_ID
    - LIC_NUMERO
    - LIC_SAI_ID
- SAI_SAISON
    - SAI_ID
    - SAI_LIBELLE
```

(i edited my question to simplify the issue at max)

There are multiple LIC_LICENCE per LIC_NUMERO.
Each LIC_LICENCE is linked to only one SAI_SAISON by the SAI_ID field.

I want, for each LIC_NUMERO, to get the one LIC_LICENCE corresponding to the greater season ( max(SAI_LIBELLE) ).

Every tries i did gave me all the LIC_LICENCE.

Example of data :
LIC_LICENCE

- LIC_ID / LIC_NUMERO / LIC_SAI_ID
- 101    /   2001     /    9001
- 102    /   2001     /    9002
- 103    /   2001     /    9003
- 104    /   2002     /    9003
- 105    /   2002     /    9002

SAI_SAISON

- SAI_ID  /  SAI_LIBELLE
- 9001    /  "2021/2022"
- 9002    /  "2020/2021"
- 9003    /  "2019/2020"

Result expected would be (LIC_ID / LIC_NUMERO / SAI_LIBELLE) :

- 102 / 2001 / "2021/2022"
- 105 / 2002 / "2020/2021"

Edit :

So... I was able to get a solution, but i'm not sure it is the most efficient :

```
SELECT DISTINCT L4.LIC_NUMERO, SS.SAI_LIBELLE \
FROM LIC_LICENCE AS LL \
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM LIC_LICENCE AS L3 \
  LEFT JOIN SAI_SAISON AS S ON S.SAI_ID = L3.LIC_SAI_ID \
  WHERE L3.LIC_NUMERO = LL.LIC_NUMERO ORDER BY S.SAI_LIBELLE DESC ) AS L4 \
INNER JOIN SAI_SAISON AS SS ON SS.SAI_ID = L4.LIC_SAI_ID \
ORDER BY L4.LIC_NUMERO ;
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. Tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: I don't have access for now to a database i can create tables and insert some data. I'm read-only on this one. I'll try to get a hand on one to test.
To answer the question, the database is SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

CROSS APPLY has its use, but this is not one of them. Try with join to a inner query like this:

````
FROM LIC_LICENCE AS LL \
JOIN (SELECT LIC.LIC_LICI_ID, MAX(LIC.LIC_SAI_ID) AS LIC_SAI_ID \
      FROM LIC_LICENCE AS LIC \
      GROUP BY LIC.LIC_LICI_ID) LIC2 \
     ON LIC2.LIC_LICI_ID = LL.LIC_LICI_ID AND LIC2.LIC_SAI_ID = LL.LIC_SAI_ID \
INNER JOIN SAI_SAISON AS SS ON SS.SAI_ID = LL.LIC_SAI_ID \
ORDER BY LL.LIC_NUMERO ;```
````

As I do not have the database with me, correct any syntax issue if you see(it will be fixed if found).

Comment: Oh, i edited my question when you were typing your answer.

Comment: Updated my answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks. But I wasn't able to make your answer work. The issue is that MAX() should be applied on SAI_LIBELLE, not on SAI_ID. That makes the thing harder.

Comment: In the example data given, latest records are being created with decreasing IDs. Real world data mostly does not act that way. Anyway, in your case instead of MAX, use MIN on SAI_ID. It should work.

Comment: In real world, SAI_ID is a UUID… that’s why i simplified it here for easy reading. :)

Comment: Do you still need LIC_ID, as the solution you found does not have it. An easier approach to get the result that you got would be:                                               
SELECT LL.LIC_NUMERO,MAX(S.SAI_LIBELLE) AS SAI_LIBELLE FROM LIC_LICENCE LL
JOIN SAI_SAISON S ON S.SAI_ID=LL.LIC_SAI_ID
GROUP BY LL.LIC_NUMERO

Comment: Yes, sadly, i need some more fields from LIC_LICENCE (that i didn’t put in here) like LIC_ID, and so i can’t use this because they would not be in order by.